# Remove displayed picture from background

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a script to upload a picture. It changes automatically but when I use the script it displays another large picture in the background of the page. I want to remove the picture that shown in the background of my page.
this is my script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(window).load(function(){
      $('#i_file').change( function(event) {
         $("img").fadeIn("fast").attr('src',URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]));
       });
    });
</script>
```

and here is my button

```
<input type="file" id="i_file" name="Img" value="" />
```

---

I can't post picture here so i used prntscr anyway here's the original post

http://prntscr.com/750zg2

and here's what's happening after upload another picture

http://prntscr.com/7510vj

Comment: Could you provide a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: `input type file` is your button ?

Comment: if you mean call function on load its deprecated and removed now its ajax call to load url, you need to user `.on('load', ... ` , and did you tried use `.ready` instead of 'load'?

Comment: Yes input type is my button to upload picture

Comment: `$('#i_file').change( function(event) { $("body").css('background-image',"url("+URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0‌​])+")"); });` This will help you change the background image of the page. But remember, this change will be lost on page reload.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid picture to be displayed in background